# Приложение в свернутом виде изменяет название

Tags: android

Добрый день. У меня возникла следующая проблема: мое приложение состоит из нескольких активити. При сворачивании приложения, например, из активити "activity name 1" (надпись на экшен баре) в списке свернутых приложений приложение именуется "activity name 1". Такое поведение присутствует на Андроид 4.1 - 4.4.
 Мне же необходимо чтобы в свернутом виде приложение всегда называлось "App name"
Данное поведение объясняется тем, что в файле манифеста для каждой активити у меня прописан параметр

```
<activity android:label="@string/activity_name_..." ... />
```

так же для самого приложения прописанно

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ... />
```

К сожалению просто убрать лейблы для активити из манифеста и в каждой из них прописать setTitle() для экшен бара крайне не желательно, так как все активити наследуются от базовой и в базовой создается кастомный экшен бар, который и использует activity label. 
 Возможно ли заставить приложение именоваться в свернутом виде всегда "App name", при этом не меняя манифест?

activity name 1:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);

        setupActionBar(getTitle());
```

base activity:

```
protected void setupActionBar(CharSequence title) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_action_bar_title)).setText(title);
            actionBar.show();
        }
    }
```

layaut actionbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/action_bar_custom"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/primary_color"
                android:padding="0dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_logo"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_action_bar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/action_bar_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/action_bar_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/text_icons"
        tools:text="HALLO!"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в `onPause()` ставить другой заголовок активити вызовом вашего же метода, а в `onStart()` его менять обратно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так тоже думал поступить, но подумал что это костыль. К сожалению этот метод не сработал, я провел несколько экспериментов в том числе переписал метод таким образом `setupActionBar((getString(R.string.app_name));` итогом было в экшен баре всегда было название приложения а в свернутом виде приложение по прежнему подписывалось как в манифесте  `<activity android:label="@string/activity_name_..." ... />` . Таким образом получается что без изменения манифеста ничего не получится.